# Downloading a file using requests without the file URL in Python

Tags: python, reporting-services, python-requests

I'm using `requests` in Python to download a report that is created in SSRS (SQL Server Reporting Services). So I don't actually have the URL of the Excel/PDF/CSV file. I only have the link which generates the file (when a certain URL is clicked, it will prompt a download in the browser). The URL is something like `www.reportserver.com/reportname&rs:Format=EXCEL.`

```
 s = requests.Session()
 s.get(report_URL)
 s.post(report_URL, data={'_username': 'username', '_password': 
 'password'})

 with open(file.xlsx, 'wb') as output:
     output.write(s.content)
```

The problem is that this generates an empty file (0 KB) no matter how I save it.

How can I download a file whose actual download is triggered by navigating to a URL (which itself requires a login) using `requests`?

Comment: @DaleBurrell oops. Any ideas on how to fix the problem, though?

Comment: No because as yet I don't know what the problem is - which is why I'm asking questions. What do the headers of the response show? You need to debug the response to work out whether you've actually connected or not.

Comment: You're still doing a `GET` followed by a `POST` - why?

Comment: I'm looking to see if anyone here knows the right way to go about downloading a file when I don't have the direct URL for that file. The URL triggers a download which I want the code to interpret using `requests`. Do the `get` and `post` statements need to be reversed?

Comment: I'm asking how the current code is *intended* to work, and from there I may be able to assist. But I need to know what you were trying to accomplish with the get and post done that way.

Comment: A quick google shows https://github.com/russlamb/py_ssrs_download/blob/master/download_ssrs.py

Comment: And https://pypi.org/project/sspyrs/

Comment: If the `POST` is an attempt to login, then you of course need to login before you try and `GET` your report, and you'll need to pass the cookies collection returned by the post to the `GET` to pass your authentication. Thats assuming you use forms authentication for SSRS.

Comment: Thanks @DaleBurrell, I ended up using `requests_ntlm` for authentication, which works. I have still had two problems with using only `requests`: 1. Sometimes the `POST` request hangs and times out, and 2. When it does `GET`, the Excel file is empty (0 KB). Perhaps I'm not properly passing the cookies to the `GET`? How would I do that? What I had was just `r.post(url, data={'_username': 'username', '_password': 'password'})`, then `r.get(url)`. When I try to download using `iter_content`, the file is empty. Is it likely that the login was not successful?

Comment: Please post a new question with a clear MVCE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.